# CPU with more than 2 modes

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

Im new to "Operating Systems" to please just dont blast me.

I studied the User Mode and the Kernel Mode of the CPU. I've just discovered that some CPU has intermediate modes beetween user and kernel mode.
But why is this necessary ? Is it dangerous to use always kernel mode for privileged instructions ? Or is a matter of prestations ?

Comment: What CPU? You have to pick an architecture to start with.

Comment: Read wikipage on [protection rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring). Linux don't use all of them (only 0 for kernel, 3 for user mode) on x86. Read also more about [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64). Read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) - freely downloadable. See [OSDEV](http://osdev.org/). Your question is off-topic here (unrelated to some [MCVE])

Comment: BTW, *prestation* is not a usual English word (but a French one). Please explain your last sentence.

Comment: Read also wikipage on [System Management Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode) - mostly for the BIOS.  Read more about the [Intel Management Engine](https://www.fsf.org/blogs/sysadmin/the-management-engine-an-attack-on-computer-users-freedom)

Comment: It looks you did not understand [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48328744/841108) to your previous question (you basically have to be in kernel mode to run privileged instructions, they won't run in user mode, otherwise they won't be privileged). If something is unclear there, please comment my answer, and I'll improve it again.

Comment: BTW, if you followed all the references in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48328744/841108), you would not need to ask this one!

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been upvoted. It is a near duplicate of the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48328628/841108) by the same author, to which I have [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48328744/841108). It also could be seen as off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VAX/VMS system is one that used four modes. VMS works quite differently from Eunuchs. In Eunuchs variants you have a shell process. Each time you run a program you create a new process. In fact, the shell in Eunuchs variants is just a program with nothing special about it.

In VMS, the the command interpreter exists in the same process as the running program. Programs can (and often do) interact with the command interpreter. When your program ends, the command interpreter takes back control. Run another program and you remain in the same process with a new executable loaded.

The command interpreter runs in "supervisor mode" which is one level higher than user mode. It is then protected from the user mode access messing with it. As the same time, any bugs in the command interpreter will not cause the system to crash.

Also the debugger exists in supervisor mode within the process it is debugging.

For people brought up under Windoze and Eunuchs you cannot appreciate how primitive their file handling is. VMS, like most real non-toy operating systems, has different file structures. It supports stream files like Eunuchs and Windows. However, it also supports sequential file structures, fixed record file structures and files indexed on keys. The system services for managing this run in executive mode (above supervisor and below kernel). Again, that allows having protected system services that will not crash the entire operating system.

I should also mention that non-toy operating systems support file versions. If you open a document, edit it, and save it, you create a new version of the file with the same name. If you make a misteak or eror you can go back and fix it.

The general answer to your question is these other modes provide means for the operating system to provide interfaces to services that are otherwise protected from users messing with that will not affect the entire operating system when there are problems.

Ideally, an operating system would do as little as possible in kernel mode. When you have operating systems that are quick and dirty and do very little, they just use kernel mode.